# Possible to using headers detect plugins used on third party wordpress websites?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to find out what version of plugins and their name are installed on WordPress, on a remote domain.

```php
function getHeader($domain)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL =>$domain,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> true,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    return array($header,$body);
}
```

also if possible to know plugins versions

Comment: Any site which gives away that kind of info (whether on purpose or not) is asking to be hacked, really (e.g. if it gives away the fact that they are running out of date versions, or versions with known issues). Most will avoid doing so, if they are sensible. What's your reason for wanting to detect this info on a remote site?

Comment: P.S. You only asked this a few minutes ago already: [how to detect which plugins and versions of the plugins installed on wordpress - using php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76157853/how-to-detect-which-plugins-and-versions-of-the-plugins-installed-on-wordpress). Don't post duplicate questions please, it wastes everyone's time. If it was closed for a reason last time, why do you expect that posting the exact same thing again will give a different result?? Have a look at [ask] to get more guidance on asking useful stuff, and doing adequate research beforehand.

Comment: @ADyson working to secure my own web site, I found some website which deting this kind of information, and I very interesting how it do so

Comment: _"I found some website which deting this kind of information"_ - If your website doesn't actively expose this info (which it, as already stated, should _never_ do), then they probably have other methods. One could be as simple as creating some checksum of each included JS/CSS file on the page and compare them to known plugins and versions (which works unless you minify and concatenate your JS/CSS). That's just one of many ways you could try and do it. It could also check if specific JS variables/functions or CSS classes are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress's REST API has an [endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/plugins/#definition-example-request-2) for handling plugins. A GET request like this should get you a list from example.com.

```
curl https://username:app-password@example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/plugins
```

For this to work you'll need the username of an administrator and an app password created for this purpose by that administrator.

Hosting companies keep track of requests to API endpoints like this to help resist credential-stuffing and other attacks. I've made the mistake of using a wrong password on a REST API endpoint, and found that the hosting service blocked my IP address. So use the right credentials the first time.